# OpenDJ UID uniqueness per base dn?

Tags: opendj

Suppose I have two base dns, dc=tenant1 and dc=tenant2, when I enable uid uniqueness plugin(adds both these two base dns to property ds-cfg-base-dn

and then I can not have a same user with uid=uid1,ou=People,dc=tenant1 and uid=uid1,ou=People,dc=tenant2

Does OpenDJ has a way that can make this happen ? I mean a same uid but in different basedn ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure 2 (or more) different instances of the UID uniqueness plugin, each having a single base DN of the tenant (and different names).